# OGM and ORM named queries in xml file

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, configuration, hibernate-ogm

My application contains both ORM  and OGM. For ORM I was wrote some named queries in xyz.hbm.xml. But while using OGM those queries caused for exception. I am using OGM 4.1.3.Final version. Please help someone.

example.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Jan 1, 2015 1:53:57 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="mkcl.os.apps.edumiss.model.student.Admission" table="ADMISSION">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="ADMISSION_ID" />
            <generator class="uuid" />
        </id>
        <property name="studentId">
            <column name="STUDENTID" />
        </property>

        <property name="schoolId">
            <column name="SCHOOL_ID" />
        </property>

        <property name="academicYearId" type="int">
            <column name="ACADEMICYEARID" />
        </property>
        <property name="sectionRollNumber" type="int">
            <column name="SECTIONROLLNUMBER" />
        </property>

        <property name="admissionDate" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="ADMISSIONDATE" />
        </property>

        <property name="schoolLeavingDate" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="SCHOOL_LEAVING_DATE" />
        </property>

        <property name="standardId" type="short">
            <column name="STANDARDID" />
        </property>
        <property name="standardName" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="STANDARD_NAME" />
        </property>

        <property name="sectionId">
            <column name="SECTION_ID" />
        </property>

        <property name="sectionName">
            <column name="SECTION_NAME" />
        </property>

        <property name="reasonForLeaving">
            <column name="REASON_FOR_LEAVING" />
        </property>

        <property name="streamId" type="short">
            <column name="STREAM_ID" />
        </property>

        <property name="streamName" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="STREAM_NAME" />
        </property>

        <property name="admissionType" column="ADMISSION_TYPE">
            <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
                <param name="useNamed"></param>
                <param name="enumClass">mkcl.os.apps.edumiss.model.student.AdmissionType</param>
            </type>
        </property>

        <property name="createdBy" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="CREATED_BY" />
        </property>

        <property name="createOn" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="CREATED_ON" />
        </property>

        <property name="modifiedBy" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="MODIFIED_BY" />
        </property>

        <property name="lastModified" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="LAST_MODIFIED" />
        </property>

        <property name="patternId" type="integer">
            <column name="PATTERN_ID"></column>
        </property>

    </class>

    <sql-query name="getAdmissionForAcademicYear">
        <return alias="admission" class="mkcl.os.apps.edumiss.model.student.Admission"></return>
        <![CDATA[
        SELECT
        {admission.*}
        FROM
        ADMISSION admission
        INNER JOIN STUDENT s
        ON
        s.CURRENT_ADMISSION_ID = admission.ADMISSION_ID
        WHERE
        admission.STUDENTID = :mkclIdentificationNumber
        AND
        admission.ACADEMICYEARID = :academicYearId
        ]]>
    </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

this throws

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode has interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
```

if I am removing above query from hbm file then it worked fine. But I have to keep those queries in .hbm.xml file as it is.

Comment: Something with the dependencies in your project seems incorrect. Could you share your runtime classpath and the complete stacktrace so we can see where it's coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to current version of OGM(5.0) feature document:
Model can not possible to share between OGM and ORM together and this will projected to resolve in next version of OGM.

ORM classes can try to parse the .hbm.xml file and find the named queries which having the syntax of mongo query. so while reading the file OGM unable to parse the syntax of SQL named query and throws an error so I have only way to shift the all the queries into another hbm whose wntry will not be present in nosql_hibernate.xml file so OGM will not parse and my code will run fast else till this feature not support shift to another framework.

Answer (score 1):

That query is for a relational database, so you don't need the OGM for that.
Why do you want to run an SQL query against OGM, which is for NoSQL?

The default `hibernate.archive.autodetection` property value is `class,hbm`, so make sure you set it to `class` in the `persistence.xml` file that's associated to the OGM EntityManagerFactory. You do have two separate `persistence.xml` configurations (one for ORM and one for OGM), right?

Comment: I don't want to run that query for OGM. I mentioned my application have both ORM and OGM connection. In another scenario I want use this query (around 1000s of such queries already present in my app). But according to new scenario I need to integrate application with mongodb using old model and hbm.xml. So it needed. It executes with ORM itself(with mysql).

Comment: I think there should be separate EntityManagerFcatories for ORM and OGM so they shouldn't collide. For OGM you should not allow it to inspect hbml files at all.

Comment: Yes I made separate EntityManager but while creating sessionFactory for mongodb it scans whole .hbm.xml which mentioned in hibernate_mongoDB.cfg.xml. And which could broken the code.